# For the Application.Run method, what is "a Range object indicating where the function is"?

Tags: vba, excel

What does it mean that a **Range** object can be a parameter of the [Application.Run Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run)?

The documentation says the first parameter is "the macro to run. This can be either a string with the macro name, a **Range** object indicating where the function is, or a register ID for a registered DLL (XLL) function. If a string is used, the string will be evaluated in the context of the active sheet."

Does it mean a range with a function name or with code? None of my tests work:

```
Public Function TestFunctionA()
    MsgBox "It works!"
End Function

Sub FirstTestOfRunFromRange()
'Function name in a cell
    Dim rngA As Range
    Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    rngA = "TestFunctionA"
    Application.Run "TestFunctionA"
    Application.Run rngA
End Sub

Sub SecondTestOfRunFromRange()
'Function code in a cell
    Dim rngA As Range
    Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    rngA = "Public Function TestFunctionB()" & _
        vbCrLf & "MsgBox ""It works!""" & _
        vbCrLf & "End Function"
    Application.Run rngA
End Sub

Sub ThirdTestOfRunFromRange()
'Function code as one line per cell
    Dim rngA As Range
    Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    rngA.Offset(0, 0) = "Public Function TestFunctionB()"
    rngA.Offset(1, 0) = "MsgBox ""It works!"""
    rngA.Offset(2, 0) = "End Function"
    Set rngA = rngA.CurrentRegion
    Application.Run rngA
End Sub

Sub FourthTestOfRunFromRange()
'Function code as one line in one cell
    Dim rngA As Range
    Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    rngA = "Public Function TestFunctionB(): MsgBox ""It works!"": End Function"
    Application.Run rngA
End Sub

Sub FifthTestOfRunFromRange()
'Code step in a cell
    Dim rngA As Range
    Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    rngA = "MsgBox ""It works!"""
    Application.Run rngA
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd take anything you read on learn.microsoft.com with a grain of salt. The "new" documentation is complete trash.

Comment: Adding what "None of my tests work" means _might_ be useful e.g. any error messages?

Comment: @QHarr It's an error 1004, but I've verified that in fact none of them work (all error 1004s). I don't remember ever seeing `Range` referred to as a parameter on the old MSDN Excel object model documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option for a range parameter for `Application.Run` refers to an `Excel 4 Macro` ie a `Range` set to the first cell of a macro on a `Macro` Sheet.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's some obscure information there... I'll have to remember that next time I open up a workbook created around 1992. #TIL and hats off on that answer.